# Dynamically allocated array in functions - program not working, cannot figure out why

Tags: c++

Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8

Programming level: beginner.

Using pointers, and arrays (no vectors) I have to create a program that:

1) survey user to input how many movies each student saw

2) create an array of said student size sample, and store data

3) calculate mean, median

**Here is a copy of the program without functions, it runs as intended, its just a huge main and looks bloated:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sortFunction(int student[], int numberOfStudents);

int main(){

    int count = 0,
        countB = 0,
        numberOfStudents,
        tempVarA,
        tempVarB,
        tempVarC,
        x = 0;

    int* student;

    double  mean,
            total = 0;

    cout << "How many students were surveyed?\n";
    cin >> numberOfStudents;

    numberOfStudents--; 

    student = new int[numberOfStudents];



    cout << "Enter the number of movies watched per student:\n";
    count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < numberOfStudents+1; count++){

        cout << "How many movies did Student Number " << (count + 1) << " see?\n";

        cin >> student[count];

        total += student[count];

    };


    mean = total / (1+numberOfStudents);

    cout << "The mean number of movies watched per student, is: " << mean << ".\n";

    cout << "The median number of movies watched is: ";


    int g = 0;

    while (g < numberOfStudents)

        for (count = 0; count < numberOfStudents; count++)

            if (student[count] > student[count + 1]){

                tempVarA = student[count];
                tempVarB = student[count + 1];

                student[count] = tempVarB;
                student[count + 1] = tempVarA;

                g = 0;  
            }

            else g++;
    ;


    tempVarC = numberOfStudents + 1; // MAKE ARRAY SIZE ACTUAL NUMBER

    if (tempVarC % 2 == 0) {

        double medianEven = (student[tempVarC / 2] + student[tempVarC / 2 - 1]) / 2.00;
        cout << medianEven << endl;
    }

    else{
        int medianOdd = tempVarC / 2;
        cout << student[medianOdd] << endl;
    }

    for (countB = 0; countB < numberOfStudents + 1; countB++) { 
        cout<<student[countB] << endl;
    }



return 0;
}
```

**Here is a copy of the program with functions, which spews out an error:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sortFunction(int studentarray[], int studentnumber){

    int g = 0,
        tempVarA,
        tempVarB,
        count,
        countF;

    while (g < studentnumber){

        for (countF = 0; countF < studentnumber; countF++){

            if (studentarray[countF] > studentarray[countF + 1]){

                tempVarA = studentarray[countF];
                tempVarB = studentarray[countF + 1];

                studentarray[countF] = tempVarB;
                studentarray[countF + 1] = tempVarA;

                g = 0;

            }

            else g++;
        }
    }

    for (count = 0; count < studentnumber; count++)
        return studentarray[count];
}



int input(int studentarray[], int numberOfStudents){

    int countF = 0,
        countS = 0;

    for (countF = 0; countF < numberOfStudents; countF++){

        cout << "How many movies did Student Number " << (countF + 1) << " see?\n";

        cin >> studentarray[countF];

    };
    for (countS = 0; countS < numberOfStudents; countS++)
        return studentarray[countS];
}





int main(){                                                 //main function
    int count = 0,                                          //declare global variables
        countB = 0,
        numberOfStudents,
        tempVarA = 0,
        tempVarB = 0,
        tempVarC,
        x = 0;

    int*    student=0;                                      //declare pointer array

    double  mean,                                           //declare double global variables
            total = 0;

    cout << "How many students were surveyed?\n";           //request  survey size, to set array size
    cin >> numberOfStudents;                                //get user input

    numberOfStudents--;                                     //lower size by 1, to remove extra count from count 0

    //student[numberOfStudents];                                //set dynamic array size

    input(student, numberOfStudents);                       //call input function with proper array size

    mean = total/(numberOfStudents + 1);                    //calculate mean


    cout << "The mean number of movies watched per student, is: " << mean << ".\n";

    cout << "The median number of movies watched is: ";


    sortFunction(student, numberOfStudents);                //call sorting function


    tempVarC = numberOfStudents + 1; 

        if (tempVarC % 2 == 0) {

            double medianEven =(student[tempVarC / 2] + student[tempVarC / 2 - 1]) / 2.00;
            cout << medianEven << endl;
        }

        else{
            int medianOdd = tempVarC / 2;
            cout << student[medianOdd] << endl;
        }
}
```

The error is: **C4715: : not all control paths return a value** (for both input and sort functions)

I know this is related to the way the function returns the values back to the array, but I cannot figure out how to properly implement this. I feel like there is a fundamental concept which I am misunderstanding - this is my first time using dynamically allocated arrays in functions.

Thanks a lot, any comment on how I write my code/cleanliness would also greatly appreciated.

Comment: `not all control paths return a value` means that you have a function, like `int main()` that does not return anything. For `int main()`, add `return 0` at the end. For `int input()`, it's trying to "return" on every single loop (it can only return once, not each loop iteration), and that error also indicates that after that `for()` loop, there should be some kind of return value.

Comment: Too much code! Too unclear question! Try too narrow the source of your problem by debugging, and watching the values changing line by line. Come back to ask a question, if you stumble over a particular behavior you can't understand, or that can't be explained by the current c++ standards,

Comment: Your "for" loop at the end makes no sense.  a return will exit the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
Compiler is signaling that functions:
sortFunction
input
not always return a value. The case is, when argument numberOfStudents have value equal to '0', the body of for loop won't execute (because `countS` is 0 and `numberOfStudents` is 0 and value of `(countS < numberOfStudents)` is false.
In that case, the is no return statement in function.
And, of course, the is no return in main function.

Second:
There is no sense in the code below:

```
for (count = 0; count < studentnumber; count++)
        return studentarray[count];
```

because if `studentnumber` is greater then `0` it will always return the first value from array 'studentarray'.

Comment: so without the for loop, how would I go about creating a loop that returns the values of the array after sorting the whole thing?

Comment: You can't return each value separatly, but you can return whole array, or modify array passed as argument. You need to know, that when you are passing dynamically allocated array, represented by pointer, to another function, you don't send copy of array, but just information wher that array is located. So, in your code, function `sortFunction` is working directly on array `student`, because in main function you passed information about it's location. So...you don;t need to return new array, because you just sorted `student` array from main function.

Comment: If you just want the array sorted, change the return type to void, and don't worry about returning the array, as it is passed by reference, and sorted in place when the function is called.

Comment: PS. I believe you misunderstood the idea of return statement. It means: stop executing function, go back to place where it was called, take one value with you (result) or no value (if just `return;` with no argument is used).